# How can i change the background color of my todo when todo is complete. I have used local storage to store my todos

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can i change the background color of the todo when todo is complete. I am calling the taost notification when todo duedate is expired at the same time i want the backgroud color to change.

I want to change the background color of todo when it's time expires.

```
const Todos = ({ todos}) => {
 return (
   <ListGroup className="mt-5 mb-2 items">
     {todos.map(todo => (
       console.log("test",todo.data[2]),
       <ListGroupItem key={todo.id} style={{background: todo.data[2] === 'true' ? '' : 'white'}}>
         {todo.data[0]}
         <span>
         <BsFillCalendar2RangeFill/> &nbsp;
         {todo.data[1]}
         </span>
       </ListGroupItem>
     ))}
   </ListGroup>
  );
};
```

```
toast.configure()
const TodoForm = ({ addTodos }) => {
  const [todoString, setTodoString] = useState("");
  const [duedate, setDuedate] = useState("")
  const [theme,setTheme] = useState("");

  const showToast = (data) => {
    toast.info('Due date of the task - '+ data+' is expired' ,{autoClose:10000})
    setTheme(true);
  }
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const todo = {
      data: [todoString,duedate,theme],
      id: v4()
    };
    addTodos(todo);
    var splittime = todo.data[1].split(":");
    var expirationtime = splittime[0]*3600+splittime[1]*60+splittime[2]*1;
    var today = new Date()
    var time = today.getHours()*3600+today.getMinutes()*60+today.getSeconds();
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => showToast(todo.data[0]), Math.abs(expirationtime-time)*1000);
    return () => { 
      clearTimeout(timeout) 
    };
};
return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <FormGroup>
        <InputGroup>
          <Input type="text" name="todo" id="todo" placeholder="Enter a todo string" value={todoString} onChange={e => setTodoString(e.target.value)}/>
          
            <Input type="text" name="duedate" placeholder="HH:MM:SS" format="HH:mm:ss" value={duedate} onChange={e => setDuedate(e.target.value)}/>
           
            <Button color="success">Add Todo</Button>
         </InputGroup>
      </FormGroup>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default TodoForm;
```

How can i change the background color of the todo when todo is complete. I am calling the taost notification when todo duedate is expired at the same time i want the backgroud color to change.

I want to change the background color of todo when it's time expires.

Comment: You haven't shared where `todos` and `setTodos` resides, but I'll just say you'll probably just a function that checks the complete status and sets a todo property for the `Todos` renderer to check and set the background accordingly.

Comment: `const App = () => {
 const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
 useEffect(() => {
    const localTodos = localStorage.getItem("todos");
    if (localTodos) {
      setTodos(JSON.parse(localTodos));}
  }, []);
const addTodos = async todo => {
    setTodos([...todos, todo]);};useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
  }, [todos]);
return (
    <Todos todos={todos}/>
      <TodoForm addTodos={addTodos} />
  );};
`

Comment: Please add any new relevant details as edits to your question. The comments area isn't a good place for posting code if you want it to be readable.

Answer (score 0):

I think It's very simple.

```
return !loading &&  (<Component style={{ backgroundColor: item.isCompleted ? '#yourcompletedcolor': '#yourcolor'}} />);
```

Comment: I have tried this in todo compoment while rendering the todos but its not working.              {todos.map(todo => (
       console.log("test",todo.data[2]),
       <ListGroupItem key={todo.id} style={{background: todo.data[2] === 'true' ? '' : 'white'}}>
         {todo.data[0]}
         <span>
         <BsFillCalendar2RangeFill/> &nbsp;
         {todo.data[1]}
         </span>
       </ListGroupItem>
     ))}

Comment: Did you check todo.data[2] from console.log(). Does it return true or false ?. Also you can change style 'backround' to 'color'. because i am not sure to the styling parameters.

Comment: It is returning false because it is not setting theme to true. styling is correct but i am not set the theme when toast notification is coming.